# Using an existing image with dynamicreports

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

I am exporting an existing image to DynamicReports:

```
public class DReportSample {

    public DReportSample() {
        build();
    }

    private void build() {  
            StyleBuilder boldStyle         = stl.style().bold();
            StyleBuilder boldCenteredStyle = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment
                    (HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            //BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1200,1200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
           BufferedImage img = null;
try {
   // img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/Hysteresis.png"));
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/Hysteresis.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
        try {
            report()//create new report design
                         // .setColumnTitleStyle(boldStyle)
                         // .setColumnStyle(boldStyle)
                          .highlightDetailEvenRows()
              .columns(//add columns

                col.column(null,"Col_1",      type.stringType()),
                col.column(null,"Col_2",  type.stringType())
                                )
                           .summary(
        cmp.verticalList()
            .add(cmp.text("\n\nHYSTERISIS PLOT").setStyle(boldStyle))

            .add(cmp.image(img))  // Add the exported chart image to the report.

    )
              .title(cmp.text("XYZ Hospital").setStyle(boldCenteredStyle))//shows report title
              .pageFooter(cmp.pageXofY())//shows number of page at page footer
              .setDataSource(createDataSource())//set datasource
              .show();//create and show report
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But the problem is the image appears to be fixed size say (300,300) pixels. I want it to appear as bigger size,

I tried to resize my image to its double size manually, and then using above code but it again appeared of same size(300,300)

Then I tried to use resized version through my code and tried:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1200,1200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

but it did not work:

Then I tried:

```
.add(cmp.image(img.getScaledInstance(600, 600, 5)))
```

it made the image appear even smaller.

Can some one please let me know how do I import the image in my dynamicreports file with my desired dimension. Also please guide, how do i Change font style,color and size of my text.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.add(cmp.image(img).setFixedDimension(500, 400))

resolved the issue.

Can someone tell me how to change font style,color and size of my text in dynamicReports